# Give Flask error handler access to request

Tags: python, error-handling, flask

I'm trying to make a custom error page in Flask, and I'd like to give the error handler access to the request that generated the API call that caused the error so that the error page it returns can change depend on the circumstances. For instance, say there are two endpoints:

(1) `@app.route('/get_item')`

(2) `@app.route('/submit_item')`

If an error occurs during a call to `get_item`, I want to display a certain error page ("Sorry, an error occurred...") however, if an error occurs during a call to `submit_item`, I want it to say something more informative, like:

> "An error occured! Please contact us.
>
> Your user id: `request.json['userid']`
>
> Your submission id: `request.json['submission']`"

Is it possible to allow the error handler to have access to this, or do I just have to wrap the whole of `submit_item` in `try`/`except` statements?

Comment: Just use `request.url.path` or `request.url.path` , you can import request from flask

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `request` context in the error handler function,
something along those lines:

```
from flask import request

def exception_handler(*args):
    if request.url.endswith('submit_item'):
       return "MyMoreDescriptiveErrorMessage", 500
    else:
       return "Something wrong happened", 500
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a custom exception and specify an error handler for it similar to [this example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/apierrors/).

```
class CustomException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, message=None, status_code=None, payload=None):
        Exception.__init__(self)

        if message is None:
            message = "Sorry, an error occurred..."

        self.message = message

        if status_code is not None:
            self.status_code = status_code
        self.payload = payload


@app.errorhandler(CustomException)
def handle_custom(error):
    response = render_template('error.html', message=error.message)
    response.status_code = error.status_code
    return response

@app.route('/submit_item')
def submit_item():
     message = "An error occured! Userid: %(userid)d, submission: %(submission_id)d"
     message = message % (request.json)

     raise CustomException(message)
```